# Responsive Images Not Scaled-Down Properly in Omega Theme just on Firefox

Tags: media, theming

I'm building a responsive site using the Omega theme, and Adaptive Image Styles. So, in my Firefox 16.0.2 (Mac) browser, images that are scaling down look very poor quality as they are scaled down. If I take the same image out of Drupal and scale it in the same browser, it looks fine; in any other browser, it looks fine. Images seem to be using proper CSS (`max-width:; height:auto;`).

Check out this snapshot. Is it a bug in my browser or where does the issue exist?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I lean towards "off-topic", as nothing in the questions ties the problem to Drupal.

Comment: I disagree in this case, as the OP says, "If I take the same image out of Drupal and scale it in the same browser, it looks fine; in any other browser, it looks fine." which leads me to think it could be a problem with the CSS styles used from the Omega theme. At least, I can give the benefit of the doubt. I would prefer to see exactly the CSS style used for the image; differently, I can only guess what the problem is.

Comment: I would argue that this is more "too localised" rather than off topic.  The question boils down to "My image doesn't look right in browser X on the Y operating system"

Comment: @Chapabu I agree: It is more too localized than off-topic. It could be considered off-topic because it involves more the browser than the server, but there are JavaScript questions that involve the browser, more than the server, and they are not automatically closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of Mac are you using? For example, I have a Retina Mac. Firefox doesn't support Retina displays, so things generally look fuzzier in Firefox than say Chrome.

Also, if the responsiveness is aimed towards mobile devices, wouldn't it be better to test on those? You probably won't have a user with a desktop window of 600px wide. ;)

Comment: Really interesting, I hadn't heard about this before. Apparently [it does affect Chrome too](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/mbp-retina-blurry-text/)

Comment: I tested this on both my pretty new macbookpro and imac. it shows like this in any of the widths, not just mobile. When the image is not at it's original size, it's very fuzzy and really bad-looking.  I'm hoping I just have bad versions of firefox, or there's problems with the way the images are shown in drupal or in firefox.... i'm totally weirded out. Thanks. What about your versions of firefox?

Comment: I have checked on multiple up-to-date firefox browsers on MAC computers for the treatment of scaled down images, and it is IN FACT noticeably worse compared to other browsers, specifically chrome and safari.

Comment: It's a terrible thing too, because I strongly prefer Firebug over Chrome Developer Tools. Often I'll move my Firefox window off my Mac and onto an external monitor. Usually I don't have any issues doing that.

Comment: Thought this would be a good update, Retina support for Mac OSX 10.7+ [link](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/18.0/releasenotes/)